# How do I sort an array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I'm new to Java, and I wrote code that sorts numbers, but I was trying to convert it to sort strings and it won't work. What is the most basic way of sorting strings in alphabetical order?

Comment: You must know about how to compare strings in java.

Comment: What about `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: @Satya - Wont work.. It sorts in Natural order, `X` will come before `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java `String`s are [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)s, meaning they have a `compareTo` method which can be used to compare two such objects. `a.compareTo(b)` will return a negative value if `a` is logically less than `b`, a positive value if `a` is greater than `b` or `0` if they are equal.

So you can keep your entire logical flow and just change the comparison check - instead of `if (name[y] > name[y+1] )` you'd need to use `if (name[y].compareTo(name[y+1]) > 0 )`.

Comment: Thank you. You just solved all my problems. Thanks for explaining and hat link to the old question was very helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do it as below:

```
Arrays.sort(name);
```

Comment: Where/how would I initialize Arrays.sort()?

Comment: `Arrays` is a Util class in Java, Just import it and you can use its methods. No need to init that, all methods are in `static`